# unable to run startup_script in gcp using terraform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform

I have below terraform script

```
resource "google_compute_instance" "vm1" {
  metadata = {
    ssh-keys = "${var.user}:${file(var.publickeypath)}"
    metadata_startup_script = <<SCRIPT
yum install -y httpd
systemctl start httpd.service
systemctl enable httpd.service
echo “Hello World from $(hostname -f)” > /var/www/html/index.html
SCRIPT
  }
}
```

now i want my startup script should be executed i can see in stratup_script is copied in my vm but not running.

for reference have a look to below image
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OHIrq.png)

even my ssh key also copied to gcp console but my startup_script should be executed.

Thanks,

Comment: Where is your `boot_disk`?

Comment: There are multiple ways to debug this. What have you tried? Suggestions: 1) SSH into the instance and rerun the startup script and review the output for problems: **sudo google_metadata_script_runner startup** 2) View the startup script logs: **sudo journalctl -u google-startup-scripts.service**

Comment: You can also have a look to the serial console to see if there is some errors at startup